# What is an efficient way to find disjoint elements in two arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following arrays:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [2,6,7,1]
```

I want to find the disjoint elements, which are as follows:

```
output = [3,4,5,6,7]
```

I was able to achieve this as follows,

```
output = A + B - (A & B)
```

but it is inefficient, as I'm adding two arrays and then removing common elements. It is similar to finding non-intersecting elements. Can I do it better than this? If so, how?

Answer (score 6):

How about just selecting elements in A not in B and elements in B not in A.

```
(A - B) + (B - A)
```

Comment: If that works, hats off to you and ruby. Plus one. Back to C++ for me.

Comment: This works, and it a good answer, but I don't see how it is any different from the OP's solution, which also uses three operations.

Comment: @sawa It is different because it is nearly 5 times slower, see benchmarks in my answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa great to see the benchmarks, very eye opening.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn This works. I've tried this. But which is more efficient?

Comment: Clearly, ` (A + B) - (A & B)` if you look at @mudasobwa's answer.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn So, that implies no other way better that `(A + B) - (A & B)` :|. I mean somehow by running loop by myself and trying it, will that be better?

Comment: No, it implies that that's the best way identified so far.  If you want to try another way, that's fine, use program that @mudasobwa provided  and stick your own method in as a fifth option and see what the timings are. If they're better timings, then use your homegrown method..

Answer (score 6):

You could use Set

```
A = Set[1,2,3,4,5]
 => #<Set: {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}> 
B = Set[2,6,7,1]
 => #<Set: {6, 1, 7, 2}> 
C = A ^ B
 => #<Set: {5, 6, 7, 3, 4}> 
C.to_a
 => [5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You don't need sort. `to_a` is enough.

Comment: Both gets an array. It's up to him if he wants the array ordered or not.

Comment: `sort` performs extra operations. The OP did not ask to sort.

Comment: This. The whole terminology of "disjoint elements" is about set operations, so why not use a set?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I added this variant to the benchmarks. It is more than 15 times slower, than the one used by OP.

Comment: @mudasobwa go for (Set.new A ^ Set.new B).to_a in the benchmark

Comment: I did benchmarks for posted answers, that fit the original question. Feel free to copy-paste the code for benchmark from my answer for granted, add as many new tests as you want, and repost the benchmark.

Comment: Converting arrays to set, is using extra space. Will it not be more inefficient?

Answer (score 5):

Another one:

```
(A | B) - (A & B)
```

But you probably want to use your own version:

```
require 'benchmark'
n = 50000
A = (1..1000).to_a
B = [2,6,7,1]
Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report { n.times do; (A + B) - (A & B); end }
  x.report { n.times do; (A - B) + (B - A); end }
  x.report { n.times do; (A | B) - (A & B); end }
  x.report { n.times do; (Set[*A] ^ Set[*B]).to_a; end }
end

       user     system      total        real
   2.200000   0.000000   2.200000 (  2.208357)
   9.600000   0.010000   9.610000 (  9.591845)
  10.630000   0.000000  10.630000 ( 10.621927)
  31.420000   0.000000  31.420000 ( 31.418155)
```

Comment: That is awesome! I never knew, we can benchmark ruby applications like this. I understand `(A + B) - (A & B)` stands out by seeing results. But, can you help me understanding results in detail?  To addon, does that means the most efficient way is same as I've posted in question?

Comment: Yes, the most efficient way seems to be the one that you have posted originally. Here we run four tests, each 50K times, and print the time was consumed by each one. As per the result, generally speaking you might just compare the values in the last column. Others are *NIX architecture specific and do not make much sense for normal application.

Comment: Got it. But it shows time, isn't it? What about space? Can we get that as well? If yes, it will be great.

Comment: No. Space might be calculated explicitly through [`ObjectSpace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/ObjectSpace.html) class and/or [`GC::Profiler`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/GC/Profiler.html).

Comment: got it. I'll try to balance between space and time :)